# HttpSession using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications, httpsession

I am trying to create a http session of 5 seconds.
Here is the code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpSession sess=req.getSession(true);;
    String fname=req.getParameter("fname");
    String lname=req.getParameter("lname");
    PrintWriter pw=resp.getWriter();
    pw.println("Hello"+" "+fname+" "+lname);
    long stime=sess.getCreationTime();
    long ltime=sess.getLastAccessedTime();
    if((ltime-stime)>5000)
    {
        pw.println("Session Expires");
        sess.invalidate();
    }
    pw.close();
}
```

The problem is when I reload the page for the 1st time after 5 seconds the session does not expire but after reloading the page 2nd time the session expires. Plz guide....

Comment: check for the value of ltime-stime, ltime and stime.

Comment: As you're always creating a new session, you always get a new session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the session expiry time:

```
// set 5 seconds
// default is 1800 seconds (30 minutes)
sess.setMaxInactiveInterval(5);
```

And after this elapsed time the session will expire automatically.

Comment: You can't play with time specially between server and client, they calculate the time differently and whenever the limit is passed, it can't be counted anymore until you refresh the page again. But in this way - like in my answer, you will ensure that the server keeps the time record and abides with it.